# SQL Server : replace null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, how to write a query in case `ItemType = MD5` then replace `Null` value as 'NAM' ?

```
 Country ItemType
  Null    MD5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CASE EXPRESSION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.ItemType = 'MD5' THEN 'NAM' ELSE t.country END as [Country],
       t.itemType
FROM YourTable t
```

If you want it only to be replace when `Country is NULL`, then replace it with this:

```
CASE WHEN t.ItemType = 'MD5' AND t.country IS NULL THEN 'NAM' ELSE t.country END
```